# Send email based on criteria after inserting document in mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, email, database

I have an api that inserts documents into a mongo collection. Based on when a document is inserted I need to send out an email 24 hours after insertion time and a sms 48 hours after insertion time. I plan to use _id to find insertion time.

My question is, what is the best way to approach this problem? One solution I have in mind is to have a script run every minute and look for documents created 24hours and 48 hours ago.

I feel this maybe an overkill as I query the db all the time, is there a better solution or is using mongo for this purpose fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the script fails for an hour, you won't send the mails that you should have sent in that 60 minutes. You should keep a tag for mail to be fault tolerant.

This can be a better idea: At each document, have fields named `isMailSent24` and `isMailSent48`. When you insert, you will always insert with `'isMailSent24': false` and `'isMailSent48': false`. Because the mails are not sent for these documents yet, obviously.

Every minute your script runs and it should follow:

1. Find documents with `'isMailSent24': false` AND `now - creationTime > 24 hours`.

This will return the documents that we didn't send the mails for 24th hour yet, and more than 24 hours have passed after its creation. Which means it's time to send the mails for them. Most of the time, `now - creationTime` will be 24 hours and 1 minute because the script runs every minute. But if your script fails for 30 minutes, it will still send the mails for the documents that created 24 hours 30 minutes ago. This is fault tolerant and a bit more good practice

2. Send the mails for those documents.
3. Modify them as `'isMailSent24': true`.

And the same routine for `'isMailSent48'`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Well for this purpose, you can maintain another collection with a TTL index for 25 hours.

When you put an entry into the main collection, insert one corresponding document into new collection with a date field on which there should be TTL index of 25 hours.

Now run a scheduler every 15 minute and checkout all the document which were created 24 hours back, verify that mail is not sent for that document and try to send the mail, once you are able to send the mail, update the document that you have send the mail and update the date field with TTL index. now after 24 our again it would be picked up for sending sms, but this time do not update the date field, so the document will be deleted by itself when it's purpose is filled.

The benefit of it is that your main collection would be free from per minute heavy query calls and subsequent updates. Second benefit is after the mail and sms both is sent, the document will be deleted by itself so no worry of cleaning it.

Now there is some fallback which I must mention, One since you changed from per minute to 15 minute there will be a lag and it won't be exact 24 hours, I think in case of mail and sms those lags are acceptable. Or you can change the frequency to 5 minutes. Other thing is I haven't thought of failure scenario like what if the mail sending is unsuccessful, Maybe you can pick up again, but in any case you should update the date field with TTL, otherwise document will be deleted before you send the sms 24 hour later.